R shiny in iframe - doctype missing
I'm pretty confused about some differences in Shiny app functioning between local and deployment instances. We're hosting a Shiny app as a Docker container, and then embedding it in an iframe on a larger website.
There are some weird inconsistencies between the two - one CSS can't render certain UTF-8 characters, like down-arrow, and one JS plugin has some issues. More precisely, the airDatePicker from shinyWidgets doesn't allow clicking on the start date and then on another date to move it, only dragging works. None of these issues exist locally.
One thing I've found is that, when I right click on the page and select View frame source, the HTML of the Shiny app doesn't start with a DOCTYPE. The javascript console also states that "the page layout might be unexpected due to Quirks mode", which I believe is related to the DOCTYPE.
Could this be related? I cannot find a way to specify the DOCTYPE in the shiny app.
When running the app locally and checking the source, <!DOCTYPE html> appears as usual.
Any ideas where things could be going wrong? These differences are very hard to debug. Unfortunately I can't provide a reprex or link the app since it's proprietary code. Other things I can think of that could possibly influence this is docker container or Apache settings (but I don't know which ones).
